# If an abstract method is invoked, what decides which of its implementing methods gets called?

Tags: java

```
abstract class A {

  // Here is an event listener that is called when an event occurs.
  // However, this event I don't want to process here but in class C.
  ...
    foo(processMe);
  ...

  // So using this abstract method I'm trying to delegate it to class C.
  public abstract void foo(String processMe);

}

class C extends A {

  // This is the method in which I'd like to handle the event,
  @Override
  public void foo(String processMe) { ... processing processMe ... }

  // ...but I have another class, class B that "steals the implementation".

}

// B extends A because there are many things B uses and implements from A.
class B extends A {

  // This method is completely unnecessary, it just has to be here as
  // abstract methods must be implemented in all extending subclasses.
  @Override
  public void foo(String processMe) { /* NOOP */ }

}
```

And the result is that every time that event occurs in `A`, the method `foo()` of `B` gets called instead of the one in class `C`.

I was expecting that `foo()` would be called in both `B` and `C`. Why is this happening and what could be a better design pattern for my problem?

---

**Update:**

I couldn't show much more of the code as it's quite complex with many async processes.

`B` and `C` are Runnables running in different Threads extending `A` to use its protected static utility methods. There is this event listener in `A` that is called when another system sends data that I'd like to process in `C`.

**Update 2:**

**I've found a bug that answers and makes the question irrelevant**, sorry.
In the abstract class I used a singleton instance to create the event handler. The thread for class `B` is created first, and when it first invokes this constructor it binds the abstract method to its own implementation which later doesn't change.

Comment: Please share the code that contains the part of the invocation of the method.

Comment: The method on the actually run-time type of the instance is being called. Since `A` is abstract that type has to be *either* `B` *or* `C`.

Comment: ... Why? If you create an instance of `C` then `B` has **nothing** to do with it, and if you create an instance of `B` then `C` has **nothing** to do with it. You might have a doubt if you had `class B extends C`... but again if `B` overrides the method, then it is overriden.

Comment: Have you created the object like A obj1 = new C(); or A obj2 = new B();

Comment: **Clearly a bug elsewhere.** From a copy bug `System.out.println("in B");` in `C.foo` to whatever. Also rebuild the project with a clean first.

Answer (score 5):

```
A a1 = new C(); 
a1.foo(); // execute foo() in C class

A a2 = new B(); 
a2.foo(); // execute foo() in B class
```

Answer (score 2):

The concrete instance that is assigned to the reference decides that.